# MYSQL - trigger for converting time in VARCHAR to seconds in INTEGER is inserting multiple rows when it should be inserting only

Tags: mysql, time, triggers

Now, this is whats up:

When I insert into *tbl_a* an row with values for time1 and time2, my trigger is inserting 2 different rows in *tbl_b*, one for each column when it should insert 1 row with values for both columns.

The purpose of this trigger is to convert a time data imported in a VARCHAR column into seconds in a INTEGER column. The catch is that the imported data can be 10:00 or 1000:00.

Although I realize that there might be an easier way to do this, I really would want to know what is wrong with this code.

Thanks in advance!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  tr_one
AFTER INSERT ON tbl_a
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.time1) = 5 THEN 
        INSERT INTO tbl_b(time1) VALUES((((SUBSTRING(NEW.time1, 1, 5) * 60) + SUBSTRING(NEW.time1, 7, 2)) * 60));
        END IF;

    IF CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.time2) = 5 THEN 
        INSERT INTO tbl_b (time2) VALUES (((SUBSTRING(NEW.time2, 1, 5) * 60) + SUBSTRING(NEW.time2, 7, 2)) * 60);
    END IF;
END
$$
```

Comment: You call `INSERT` twice, it inserts twice. Is this really surprising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting two rows because you are doing two inserts. What you need to do is figure out what both the new values are and *then* do an insert of both of them at the same time. This should do what you want:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_one
AFTER INSERT ON tbl_a
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE t1 VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NEW.time1;
    DECLARE t2 VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NEW.time2;
    DECLARE c INT;
    SET c = LOCATE(':', t1);
    IF c > 0 THEN
        SET t1 = (SUBSTRING(t1, 1, c-1) * 60 + SUBSTRING(t1, c+1)) * 60;
    END IF;
    SET c = LOCATE(':', t2);
    IF c > 0 THEN 
        SET t2 = (SUBSTRING(t2, 1, c-1) * 60 + SUBSTRING(t2, c+1)) * 60;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO tbl_b (time1, time2) VALUES (t1, t2);
END
$$
```

Note that I've been a bit more robust with the code by actually searching for the `:` between the hour and minute values and using that to control the substring selection.

Comment: That worked out beautifully. Thanks Nick!
Only one questions remains:

The IF condition where
{IF c >0}
is demanded in case the value imported for time1 is NULL?

Comment: @TiagoRibeiro the c > 0 is to deal with any situation where there isn't a `:` in the input values (for example if the value was just an empty string) and will also deal with the case when the input values are `NULL`